# What is the significance of varying the number of shots while running a circuit in a quantum machine and qasm simulator?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

what is the significance of varying the number of shots while running a circuit in a quantum machine and qasm simulator?

Does more number of shots give better/accurate result?
I am running a simple 2 qubit measurement circuit after Hadamard gates on both qubits.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform one shot, the measurement at the end of the computation gives you one of the possible results. More shots produce a distribution.

In your simple example, you should get a uniform distribution over 00,  01, 10 and 11. You should notice that, with more shots, the distribution you get is more similar to the uniform one.

Comment: so by shots effectively we to some extent  mean iterations/ no of times the circuit is executed. please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes, you are right.